# Expected use of the Stripe SetupIntents API (iOS)

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I'm looking to integrate stripe for a scenario similar to that described on this page:

- https://stripe.com/docs/payments/setup-intents
- > "A car rental company that collects payment method details before the customer rents the car and charges the card after the rental period ends"

The crucial point being that a customer may transact multiple times with us where at the point of initiation of the service the final charge value is not known.  This is still for user driven payments (not a subscription service), just where the amount is known later than the point of transaction.

The documentation appears to suggest you can/should use the PaymentSheet with a SetupIntent call to add and validate a payment method for which you can later use a server side driven PaymentIntent.

The question is when the customer returns for a second/third/etc time do they go through the PaymentSheet SetupIntents flow again each time? or should we just be reusing the previously stored payment methods.

If we are using the previous payment method are we expected to generate some custom UI to present the user with an option of which payment method to use for that transaction? rather than something like the PaymentSheet?

It would appear that using the payment sheet with a SetupIntents call multiple times does no 'damage' to the customer record other than the API log showing multiple calls, there is still a single PaymentMethod per unique type that is validated.

You do appear to be able to hijack the PaymentSheet to use purely as a payment method adder/picker, if you provide a fake intentCreationCallback clientSecret (that wasn't really generated by a backend/stripe) but that seems like an incorrect use of it.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is when the customer returns for a second/third/etc time do they go through the PaymentSheet SetupIntents flow again each time?

The intended workflow is to charge the customer off-session to limit friction, with a backend Payment Intent created with `off_session=true` and `confirm=true`:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web&ui=elements#charge-saved-payment-method

> If we are using the previous payment method are we expected to generate some custom UI to present the user with an option of which payment method to use for that transaction?

For web, you would need a custom UI, however it looks like stripe-ios has a workflow for this with the customer Sheet:
https://stripe.com/docs/elements/customer-sheet?platform=ios#ios-setup